# Get all words from text, including any special characters attached to those words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like this:

```
Here is some text.

#note Remember to look into specs #

And here is some more text.
```

I can get all words in that text using the following (str is all text):

```
str.match(/\w+/g)
```

This provides an array with all words, but the hashtag has been removed from the word **note**:

```
Here,is,some,text,note,Remember,to,look,into,specs,And,here,is,some,more,text
```

How can I get this result such that it **includes the hashtag** on the word it's attached to?

Desired result:         `Here,is,some,text,#note,Remember,to,look,into,specs,And,here,is,some,more,text`

Comment: Something like this `str.match(/#?\w+/g)`? In case you would like to play with RegExp I would recommend using [this](https://regex101.com/) tool.

Comment: @Cybernetic I believe what you want is this: [`\S*?\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/bBE636/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this be adding `.?` to your regular expression.

The `?` is a special character and means "zero or one of", and `.` means any character (special or non-special).

The combination of `.?` therefore loosely means "match an optional special character at the beginning of a word":

```
str.match(/.?\w+/g)
```

The assumption here is that you only want to match special characters at the beginning of a word (ie that are *optionally prefixed* with some special character). You can read more about the behaviour of `?` in regular expressions [at the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark)

Comment: This only works for a hashtag, the OP needs a regexp for any special char.

Comment: @Ele, can you please explain what you mean - maybe I'm just blind, but I'm not seeing the requirement for any special character being matched in the question!

Comment: See the question's title.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is using this regex `(.+?\w+)` which finds any amount of chars before a word or only a word.  This approach gets spaces as well, therefore, the function `map` removes those spaces.

**Some explanation:** https://regex101.com/r/fEBDeY/1

```js
console.log(`Here is some text.

#note Remember to look into ****specs #

And here is some more text.`.match(/(.+?\w+)/g).map(s => s.trim()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach is using the function `split` which receives a regex, this approch splits the string by spaces using this `\s+`.

```js
console.log(`Here is some text.

#note Remember to look into ****specs #

And here is some more text.`.split(/\s+/g));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it seems not work this test case `Here is# so#me text.`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `\w` metacharacter is used to find a word character.
If you want to include every character, you can use the `.` metacharacter which finds a single character (except newline or other line terminators):

`str.match(/./g)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just match the non-whitespace characters - `/(\S\w+)/gm`.

Here it is in action - https://regex101.com/r/Oj2Vhw/2/